# Wrong return from Regex.IsMatch - Regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to find in string a specific string surrounded by white spaces. For example I want receive the value true from:

```
Regex.IsMatch("I like ZaleK", "zalek",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

and value false from:

```
Regex.IsMatch("I likeZaleK", "zalek",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Here is my code:

```
Regex.IsMatch(w_all_file, @"\b" + TB_string.Text.Trim() + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ;
```

It does not work when in the w_all_file is string I am looking for followed by  "-"

For example: if  w_all_file = "I like zalek_" - the string "zalek" is not found, but if
w_all_file = "I like zalek-" - the string "zalek" is found

Any ideas why?

Thanks,

Zalek

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0):

The `\b` character in regex doesn't consider an underscore as [word boundry](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). You might want to change it to something like this:

`Regex.IsMatch(w_all_file, @"[\b_]" + TB_string.Text.Trim() + @"[\b_]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ;`

Answer (score 0):

`\b` matches at a word boundary, which are defined as between a character that is included in `\w` and one that is not.  `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so it matches underscores.

So basically, `\b` will match after the "k" in `zalek-` but not in `zalek_`.

It sounds like you want the match to also fail on `zalek-`, which you can do by using [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  Just replace the `\b` at the beginning with `(?<![\w-])`, and replace the `\b` at the end with `(?![\w-])`:

```
Regex.IsMatch(w_all_file, @"(?<![\w-])" + TB_string.Text.Trim() + @"(?![\w-])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ;
```

Note that if you add additional characters to the character class `[\w-]`, you need to make sure that the "-" is the very last character, or that you escape it with a backslash (if you don't it will be interpreted as a range of characters).

Comment: No problem, if my solution worked you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/155356) by clicking the outline of the checkmark next to the answer.  This lets others know that your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

That's what you need?

```
string input = "type your name";
string pattern = "your";

Regex.IsMatch(input, " " + pattern + " ");
```